# Statistical classification of multiple arrays

Tags: python, numpy, classification

I am working on an algorithm to mask uninteresting parts of images based on entropy. Based on samples saved as numpy arrays I am able to calculate statistics and do things like creating [boxplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYEOo.png).

My data contains the five classes:

- water
- clouds
- glacier
- foreground topography
- background topography

The task is to separate the data into two classes:

1. water, clouds
2. glacier, foreground topography, background topography

Based on visual inspection of the [boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYEOo.png) I can simply set the value to 4.7 or something close to that, but I want to apply a better and more automatic method.

My initial thought is to create two arrays from the five classes and use Mahalanobis distance to find a suitable threshold, but with my limited statistical knowledge I would like a second opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically dealing with image patch classification. Here `patch` refers to a connected subset of the image pixels.

You have to note, that this forum is meant specifically for programming issues and not really statistics. There are other [sister forums](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) which deal specifically with statistics.

Having said that,

1. Do you have labeled training data ? This means that

> Do you have subregions of an image previously marked as belonging to
>   one of the two classes ?

This is the most important thing to consider, if you want to do automatic classification.

2. In machine learning we typically do classification by extracting features from image patches. You have mentioned that you have computed certain statistics and based on that you believe that a certain threshold on the boxplot values might do the job.

> I understand that you basically want this threshold to be selected
>   automatically.

1. A much better way would be to do unsupervised K-Means clustering (to begin with !!).

> You can choose `K = 2` since you have two classes. You can do this
>   clustering over the statistics you are extracting in order to get the
>   two clusters and then checking that whether the two clusters
>   correspond to the two classes in your problem or not.

These are just some pointers based on the minimal information regarding the problem in the question. For a more thorough discussion the forum mentioned above might be a better place to enquire.

Comment: Don't answer questions that should be migrated to another stackexchange network.